# How do I sign my new React Native App [Android] with my old Expo key?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I decided to rewrite an app that was previously done with expo. When I did the first version with expo I went with the option to have expo handle that process for me.

My new app is a pure react native app for android and I'd like to submit it to the store but have no way to sign it using whatever expo used to previously sign.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these commands to get the keys generated by Expo in your previous project & then import those to the current project:

> For IOS:
>
> - `fetch:ios:certs` - Fetch this project's iOS certificates/keys and provisioning profile. Writes files to the PROJECT_DIR and print
>     passwords to stdout.
>
> For Android:
>
> - `fetch:android:keystore` - Fetch this project's Android keystore. Writes keystore to PROJECT_DIR/PROJECT_NAME.jks and prints passwords
>     to stdout.
> - `fetch:android:hashes` - Fetch this project's Android key hashes needed to set up Google/Facebook authentication. Note: if you are
>     using Google Play signing, this app will be signed with a different
>     key after publishing to the store, and you'll need to use the hashes
>     displayed in the Google Play console.

Comment: I have done this and added the generated credentials. My app was built successfully but upon uploading to google console, I'm getting this error: `You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
`

Comment: What do I do with the certificates after downloading them via fetch?